# Django: TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/login/

Tags: django

I'm following this [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication) from Mozilla.org,

***Setting up your authentication views***

And I'm having problems in this part:

***The next step is to create a registration directory on the search path and then add the login.html file.***

Because I've created that directory and the template but it appears that is not been recognize by my app.

**Structure:**

```
Note: Your folder structure should now look like the below:
locallibrary (Django project folder)
   |_catalog
   |_locallibrary
   |_templates (new)
                |_registration
```

***My Structure:***

[image]

And then for this part:

***make these directories visible to the template loader***

I've:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        #'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'DIRS': ['./templates',],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**Project url.pý:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from main_app import views



urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main_app.urls')),

]
```

For my login.html template I've:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Jumbotron Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="jumbotron.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->


    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <link href="{% static 'main_app/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

{% block content %}

{% if form.errors %}
<p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

{% if next %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Your account doesn't have access to this page. To proceed,
    please login with an account that has access.</p>
    {% else %}
    <p>Please login to see this page.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}

<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
{% csrf_token %}

<div>
  <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
  <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
</div>
<div>
  <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
  <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="submit" value="login" />
  <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</div>
</form>

{# Assumes you setup the password_reset view in your URLconf #}
<p><a href="{% url 'password_reset' %}">Lost password?</a></p>

{% endblock %}


</html>
```

**According to the tutorial I should navigate to:**

http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/

and see this:

[image]

**But I'm seeing:**

TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/login/
registration/login.html

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you must not create your template in project setting folder.

you can create template directory in your project root directory like this:

```
gallito (Django project folder)
   |_gallito
   |_templates (new)
                |_registration
```

you can see template directory is in your project root beside your app directory. not in your settings directory.

also you can move your template directory into your project template directory

Answer (score 3):

For me worked adding:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

Take care to delete browser cache.

Answer (score 3):

add your app's name gallito to INSTALLED_APPS inside the file settings.py
if your code is like this

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

then change it to this

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'gallito',
]
```

Comment: Fixed it for me!

Answer (score 3):

in my case (py3.6) it works i have  created that tempates file under main project App

```
    'DIRS': ['./templates'],
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

This should fix it.

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

*Remember:*

Django provides `no default template` for the authentication views. You should create your `own` templates for the views you want to use. The template context is documented in each view, see All authentication views.

Read this in:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views

Answer (score 2):

The Django 3.2 documentation introduces a new syntax for building file paths:

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

So the directory listing in `TEMPLATES` should look like this:

```
'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
```

This works when putting the `templates` folder as suggested by @vorujack.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have imported your template name or directory correctly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

check your settings.py file. if the app is not added in the INSTALLED_APPS, add it. LIKE
INSTALLED_APPS = [

```
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'accounts'<--- your app name
```

]

Answer (score 0):

create a new folder called **registration** inside your template folder and move your **login.html** form from template folder into **registration** folder. That is how it's work to me.

Answer (score 0):

`REST_FRAMEWORK = { 'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES':('rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',) }`

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?